# Volume of S&P500

Tags: financial-literacy, stock-analysis, market-indexes, yahoo-finance

According to the [page on Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5Egspc?ltr=1),

the volume of S&P 500 is 1,813,371,531. What is the meaning of this "volume"?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the meaning of this "volume"?

Volume of all shares in S&P 500 that were traded.

Comment: Does it mean that S&P 500 price times volume means all the transaction values of S&P 500 stocks?

Comment: @180224 Volume of individual shares at respective price, that constitute S&P 500

Comment: @180224 No, different stock has different price per shares. So simple multiplication cannot do the work, but it could be "educated" guess.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the total volume (daily shares traded) of the component stocks.

Warning: Yahoo shows a *different* (much larger) volume number in S&P 500 historical quotes and charts (and also in the "Avg. Volume" field). This is actually the NYSE Composite volume, as is seen because identical numbers appear in historical quotes and charts for ^NYA.